# finding dead functions using clang

Tags: automake, clang++

I am trying to make a tool that finds dead function
to do that I want to use `clang++` with the `flags '-S -emit-llvm'` so I could create a call graph.

The problem is this : the `.o` files that are emmited by the makefile are not object file and so cannot be linked, so  I changed the makefile so it wouldnt link the files but now `.la` files are not being created by the makefile.

Does anyone knows how to compile a project with those flags, and if not know of a way to create callgraph \ find dead functions?

Comment: Have thought about using Clang tooling to find uncalled methods using a combination of AST matchers (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html)? For instance callExpr matches on every call to a method or function.